# ruby on rails constantize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I came across the following in the model:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  #search different system user by dn
  def self.gets(sys, dn)
    sys.constantize.search(dn)
  end
end
```

I can see the purpose is to pass in different model name as `sys` and search by `dn` in those specific models.  However, I searched on `constantize` in Ruby and couldn't see any detailed explanation about this usage.

Comment: How about checking out [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+constantize)?

Comment: It’s roughly the same as `const_defined?(sys) ? const_get(sys) : recursively_lookup`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Rails documentation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/48b37f127fb44b787ae6c0710982d7949b14454f/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L258) (because constantize is a Rails method) says:

> Tries to find a constant with the name specified in the argument
>   string.

For instance, if you have a model called Foo in your application, then you can apply the constantize method to a string, which contains the exact word Foo, and it'll give you a new object with this model. Note this must be capitalized as Rails would work with your model, if you do a bad reference, then you'll get a `NameError` error:

```
NameError: wrong constant name foo
```

How does it do it?, if you go to the method definition, or if you playing with the method get an error, you'll see the source points to `activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in 'const_get'`, which is the method definition and the error source.

Between the cases the method handles internally depending on what's being received as argument, you'll see the `Object.const_get(string)` which is the way Ruby (pure) handles a "constantiz-ation", which would be the same as doing

```
Object.const_get('Foo') # Foo(...)
Object.const_get('foo') # NameError: wrong constant name foo
```

If thinking on implement this handy method, you could take a look to the Gavin Miller's [post](http://gavinmiller.io/2016/the-safesty-way-to-constantize/) from some years ago.

Answer (score 2):

When I type `'foo'.constantize` in my editor (RubyMine) and tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, it takes me to the source, `.../activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb`, with this comment:

```
# +constantize+ tries to find a declared constant with the name specified
# in the string. It raises a NameError when the name is not in CamelCase
# or is not initialized.  See ActiveSupport::Inflector.constantize
#
#   'Module'.constantize  # => Module
#   'Class'.constantize   # => Class
#   'blargle'.constantize # => NameError: wrong constant name blargle
def constantize
  ActiveSupport::Inflector.constantize(self)
end
```

It probably eventually calls `Object.const_get()`. I recommend you get a better editor, with code browsing, and you start learning your way around the Rails source code.

Comment: Or, in console, do `'Foo'.method(:constantize).source_location`.

Comment: @jvillian: on in pry, `show-source 'Foo'.constantize`. This even shows C sources (which source_location doesn't). :)

Comment: `method` returns the source location without having to invoke the method now.